# Counting the number of numbers that can be formed

Tags: combinatorics

How many ways can I arrange the digits 1,2,3,4,5 in such way that I can form 10 digit numbers? number can be repeated:

1111111111 is allowed
2222233321 is allowed too.

I know how to do it if it is the same length as the given and there is no repetition.

note: there are 10 of each digit. so 10 1's,10 2's .. 10 5's.

Answer (score 1):

Since you choose one of five digits for each of the ten places, the number of possible numbers is $5^{10} = 9765625$ possible numbers.

Answer (score 0):

for every position of a ten digit number you have 5 choices to chose a digit from {1,2,3,4,5}. And since a digit in one position is not dependent of the digit in other position so the total no of 10 digit no possible is $5\times5\times5\cdots \times5$ (10 fives) ie $5^{10}$.